sorting algorithm in x86 assembly
i know the code for this is bad and not close to working but i dont know what to do at all
im supposed to get the lowest value in the array and then swap it to the first spot and then get the second lowest and swap it to the next slot etc so just a sorting algorithm
when i run it it just doesnt do what it should be and goes to an infinite or a very long loop inside of findloop
    org 0x100 
    jmp start 
    array db 8, 3, 11, 19, 2, 6, 3
    size db 7
    
    
    
    start:
    lea ax,array 
    xor cx,cx
    mov cl, size
    push cx
    push ax
    call SortArray
    
    push cx
    push si
    call PrintArray
    
    
    mov ah,0
    int 0x16
    ret 
    
    
    PROC FindMin
        push bp
        mov bp,sp
        mov bx, [bp+4] ;array
        mov cx,[bp+ 6]  ;size
        mov si,1
        push [bx];min
        
        
        
        findloop:
            add bx,si
            mov al,[bx]
            cmp al,ah
            jnl newMin
                    
            continue: 
            
                loop findloop
            newMIn:
                mov [bp-2] ,al
                mov ah,[bp-2]  
                
        pop ax
        mov sp,bp
        pop bp    
        ret
               
    
    ENDP FindMin
    
    PROC Swap
        push bp
        mov bp,sp
        
        mov si, [bp+4] 
        mov di, [bp+6] 
        
        mov al,[si]
        mov bl,[di]
        mov [si],bl
        mov [di],al
    
            
        mov sp,bp
        pop bp    
        ret
    ENDP Swap
    
    
    PROC SortArray 
        push bp
        mov bp,sp
        
        mov bx, [bp+4] ;array
        mov cx, [bp+6] ;size
        
        sort_loop:
            dec cx       ;lower size         
            jz sort_done            ;if done jump to done
            
            push cx               
            push bx               
            call FindMin
            add bp ,4          
            add ax, cx  ;ax is the start + cx current position          
            push ax    ; save smallest index           
            push si    ; push current index           
            call Swap  ; swap smallest with current           
            pop si                
            pop cx                
            
            inc si       ; becuase the first one is now the smallest         
            jmp sort_loop
    
    sort_done:
        mov sp, bp
        pop bp
        ret 
    ENDP SortArray
    
    PROC PrintArray
        push bp
        mov bp,sp
        
        mov si, [bp+4] 
        mov cx, [bp+6]
        PRINTN  "The array is:"
        printloop:
        
            mov al,[si]
            call print_num
            inc si
            dec cx
            
            mov al, ' '
            call print_al_chr
            jmp printloop
            
        mov sp,bp
        pop bp    
        ret
        
        
    ENDP PrintArray
    
    
    
    include printing.inc   


add bp, 4 makes no sense. You probably meant add sp, 4. You unbalance the stack. FindMin sets si to 1 and does not do anything with it. Usage of bx and si in sort_loop is confusing at best.

How does the initial ah value that you're comparing against in findloop get loaded?
